# How to get a specific PHP variable to send with an AJAX call?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a simple php/mysql app that queries a bunch of employee info from a database (just 5 columns:  employee_id, first_name, last_name, x_coord, y_coord) like this...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees";
        $getemployees = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if (!$getemployees) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        } else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getemployees)) {
            $output.="<div class='employee' style='top: " . $row['x_coord'] . "px; left: " . $row['y_coord']. "px;'>". $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "</div>";
        }
        }
```

I also have this code to make the names draggable, and update my database with the new top/left positon once the draggable item is released...

```
 <script>
  $( function() {

    $('.employee').draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var left = $(this).position().left;
            var top = $(this).position().top;
            alert(left + " " + top);   //just for testing

           //Make ajax call here:
            $.ajax({
                  url: 'update-db.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {leftPosition: left, topPosition: top },   
                  success: function() { console.log('OK'); },
                  error: function() { console.log('Fail!'); }
             });
        }
    }).resizable({
        stop:function(event,ui){}
    })
  } );


  </script>
```

This all works fine, but I now realize I need to pass the "employee_id" as well, in order to update the database properly.  So how can I pass the employee_id to AJAX (along with top and left variable)?

Obviously, when I query the db in the first snippet of code at the top of this post, I need to "put" the employee_id (i.e. $row['employee_id']) somewhere so that all the draggable divs also have the corresponding employee_id info with it.  And then need to get that "employee_id" (of only the item I just dragged) into the "data" area of the AJAX call.

What is best way to do that?  I'm clearly confused at how to get just the specific employee_id passed with the AJAX call.  Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a hidden input field inside `.employee` class.

`<input type="hidden" class="employee_id" value="<?php echo $row['employee_id'];?>" name="id" />`

Now, you can easily grab this id from the ajax like below.

```
$('.employee').draggable({
    var id=$(this).find("input.employee_id").val();
    ....
```

So, your final code will be as follows,

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees";
            $getemployees = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            if (!$getemployees) {
            die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
            } else {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getemployees)) {
                    $output.="<div class='employee' style='top: " . $row['x_coord'] . "px; left: " . $row['y_coord']. "px;'>";
                    $output.="<input type='hidden' class='employee_id' value='" . $row['employee_id'] . "' />";    //Hidden input field is added containing employee Id.
                    $output.= $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];
                    $output.="</div>";
                }
            }
```

Ajax code will be,

```
<script>
  $( function() {

    $('.employee').draggable({

        var id=$(this).find('input.employee_id').val();   // this grabs the id of employee

        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var left = $(this).position().left;
            var top = $(this).position().top;
            alert(left + " " + top);   //just for testing

           //Make ajax call here:
            $.ajax({
                  url: 'update-db.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {leftPosition: left, topPosition: top, employee_id: id },   // passed id parameter to php script along with others.
                  success: function() { console.log('OK'); },
                  error: function() { console.log('Fail!'); }
             });
        }
    }).resizable({
        stop:function(event,ui){}
    })
  } );


  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you call the column containing the employee ID in the database, but I will assume for this answer it is called `employee_id`. Now update your PHP code so as to transfer the employee ID to the DOM and access it with JavaScript:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getemployees)) {
            $output.="<div class='employee' data-id='".$row['employee_id']."' style='top: " . $row['x_coord'] . "px; left: " . $row['y_coord']. "px;'>". $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "</div>";
        }
```

Now the employee ID is accessible via the `data-id` attribute of the div with a class of `employee`.
You can now access it from JavaScript:

```
// ...
data: {leftPosition: left, topPosition: top, employeeId: $(".employee").data("id") }
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add that to the data.

```
$.ajax({
              url: 'update-db.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {leftPosition: left, topPosition: top,   employeeid:employeeid },   
              success: function() { console.log('OK'); },
              error: function() { console.log('Fail!'); }
         });
```

And then the employeeid variable should be populated somewhere in the script (based on where you access the specific row). You can consider using an attribute for the dragged element and then access using 
    $(this).attr()

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send list of ids, you can use the following. I assume the employee ids list is an array object.

```
var jsonids = JSON.stringify(employee_ids);
$.ajax({
          url: 'update-db.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {leftPosition: left, topPosition: top, employeeids:  jsonids},   
          success: function() { console.log('OK'); },
          error: function() { console.log('Fail!'); }
});
```